# SQL query performance difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 1million record and i designed 2queries.

table index:

```
id = primary
bedroom = index
elevator = index
pricemeter = index
dateadd = index
```

I want to know why this query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM `p_apartmentbuy` 
    WHERE
        `sqm` > 100
        AND `bedroom` > 1
        AND `elevator` = 1
        AND `pricemeter` < 5999999
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 0, 30
) AS `alias`
ORDER BY `id` DESC, `dateadd` DESC
```

Is so much faster than this one:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `p_apartmentbuy` 
WHERE
    `sqm` > 100
    AND `bedroom` > 1
    AND `elevator` = 1
    AND `pricemeter` < 5999999
ORDER BY `id` DESC, `dateadd` DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

First query took 0.0027 sec and second query took 5.6848 sec.
Both of the result are the same as other and the variables on where clause are example.

EXPLAIN for fast query:
[image]

EXPLAIN for slow query:
[image]

Comment: What does the execution plans says?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` before `SELECT` so we can see the execution plan and make sure your SQL cache is empty before running the queries.

Comment: Reason this is faster is like some have answered. What happens is that the slower query is also ordering the dataset by `dateadd`, whereas the faster one (derived table doesn't). There is also one interesting thing being done here, called late row lookup. [The following (excellent) article](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/) explains it in detail.

Comment: Neither id nor dateadd are indexed, runs away screaming. Put an index on id, the fast one will be blistering.

Comment: @hamidreza66: how many times did you try to run both queries.  I'm leaning towards record-caching as NB hinted at above.

Comment: @vol7ron: i tried several times and the query took was same, more than 30 times

Comment: @hamidreza66: I have one more question, for due diligence.  If you remove the `dateadd` from the ordering in the second query, what kind of timing do you see?

Comment: @vol7ron I tested it before, if i remove the dateadd, query took is less than 0.002 sec, both of the id and dateadd are integer and indexed. there is no difference on query took when order by only id or only dateadd

Comment: @hamidreza66: so that just reaffirms that it's the sorting of the two columns.  The large difference in the two queries is that you might not be getting the latest `dateadd` in the results of your first query.  Because of the `30` returned, ordered by id, it's not also ordering by `dateadd`, so if you have an `id` that repeats at row 29 or 30, it might have returned the latest dateadd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we need more information about indexes, but a simple look at those queries show that they are different. They might throw different results too, its just a coincidence that they are the same (most likely based on how your data is structured). On the first query you are choosing 30 rows, ordering just by `id` (wich might have an index), and then it sorts them by `dateadd`, wich is pretty simple. Your second query has to sort all your million records by those two columns, and then choose 30, so it clearly will be more expensive.

Comment: The first query should also sort *all the million records* by `id` and indexes should only come into play in the filtering, not the ordering.  The only thing that might be screwing this up would be the internal `dateadd` ordering, because as you suggested, it's sorting two columns across many rows, instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

Second query has to sort the whole dataset by `id` and `dateadd` before it can apply limit.

The first query, on the other hand, returns early with just 30 records, which are then sorted by `id` and `dateadd`. Much less work.

Comment: The final result is sorted by `dateadd`. I am talking about these two queries as whole entities :)

Comment: You may want to change my edit back, but I find it confusing, since the second query above sorts by `id` and `dateadd` and the first query is first ordered by `id`, then limited, then of the remaining 30 sorted for `id` and `dateadd`.

Comment: @vol7ron: yes, a little bit confusing. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

Explain will confirm

But the first one is getting the first 30 records by the id, which is presumably the primary key, and so Order by id does not require a sort. Then sorting just those 30.

Whereas the second one, is getting all the records in no order, then sorting them by id and date, and then taking the first 30...

Index on dateadd, maybe?

Educated guess only though.

Answer (score 0):

Your table must use ID as the primary key. In this case, the rows are indexed with ID column and all the data is already ordered by ID.

So taking the first 30 rows is fast for the mysql plan. then order those 30 rows willl be fast.

The second query must return all the rows in order to sort according to 'dateadd' column. The LIMIT clause will then be calculated.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: ID was primary key, all field in where clause have been indexed